# restlet scripts for fetching an item from saved search in netsuite...?

Tags: netsuite

there is no limit for coding how long is the code it doesn't matter.

I want to do this because i got it from my company and i have to write a script for this any idea regarding this is accepted.

Comment: Read their [documentation](https://debugger.na1.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/Output/Help/SuiteFlex/SuiteScript/SSScriptTypes_RESTlets.html?NS_VER=2012.2.0) on their website.

Comment: I would also recommend to read the [usage limit docs](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/Output/Help/SuiteCloudCustomizationScriptingWebServices/SuiteScript/SuiteScriptGovernance-ch.html?NS_VER=2013.2.0)

Answer (score 0):

nlapiSearchRecord(type, id, filters, columns)
*Note:This API returns 1000 results at a time so if the saved search more than 1000 results then you would need to run the sorted search in a loop and concatenate with the results of the previous search*

or nlapiLoadSearch(type, id) 
*Note: This returns in 4000 results at a time*

**these API's allow to fetch the results from the saved search.**

and regarding API limit the restlet allows 5000 APIs so that's enough for serving most of the purposes. If at all you exceed this limit then you can make use of the API

nlapiYieldScript(); 
that creates the resume point and script resumes from that point.

** If any further clarification is needed please ask **

Cheers!!!!